# How to create UIView ripple circle animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uiview

I want to create UIView Animation like this link

[css3 ripple effect example](http://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/dhwzj)

i have tried all these codes in ViewDidLoad() and not working

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.75];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    animation.endProgress=1;
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

i want to create the same thing in iOS .Please help me

Comment: Try running this is 'viewDidAppear'. It is possibly completing the animation before the view becomes visible.

Comment: not working in viewdidappear also

Comment: not able to see that link, can you explain what do you want exactly?

Comment: can u open this link, so u can see a ripple circle effect..like the home screen in tinder app

Comment: http://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/dhwzj

Comment: Can you tell us which of the suggestions worked for you? and an upvote plz! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines of your code looks fine:

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.75];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];
[view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

But, the problem is that your applying the animation before adding the view to its superview. which obviously will not work!

Try, to add the subview then apply the animation. I also expect that this will not work.

if you are adding this view to its superview in the `viewDidLoad` method. apply the animation in the ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear methods.

Otherwise, create a separate method that applies the animation. and call it after you add the subview by calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you [Sample class](https://github.com/thesecretlab/UIView-Glow)

UIView+Glow is a category on UIView that adds support for making views glow (useful for highlighting a part of the screen to encourage the user to interact with it).

To learn what it can be used for, and how to use it, check out the [blog post](http://www.secretlab.com.au/blog/2012/06/23/glowing)